# It's possible to encrypt or at least obfuscate the ecryption password in a java application?

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

It's possible to encrypt or at least obfuscate the ecryption password?

Im pretty curious about encryption in java

I'm following this tutorial and it's pretty interesting but my main problem is
https://medium.com/@javatechie/spring-boot-password-encryption-using-jasypt-e92eed7343ab

when we reach this code:

```
@Configuration
public class JasyptEncryptorConfig {    @Bean(name = "jasyptStringEncryptor")
    public StringEncryptor getPasswordEncryptor() {
        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
        SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
        config.setPassword("javatechie"); // encryptor's private key
        config.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
        config.setPoolSize("1");
        config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
        config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
        config.setStringOutputType("base64");
        encryptor.setConfig(config);
        return encryptor;
    }
}
```

config.setPassword("javatechie"); // encryptor's private key
in my opinion is a huge security break someone who reach and decompile the jar will get for sure the encryption password.

So my main question is it's possible to encrypt that password or obfuscate with something in order to make a huge challenge or at least make it impossible with a simple sight get the password?

I'm just curious i tried with some kind of bit shifting "<<" but it's so simple that at the end the string with the true password needs to be hardcoded somewhere.

Comment: Irrespective of what you use to obfuscate your password. call it a password of password or anything. there will be one plaintext component that you need to pass to the program to work. now how do you pass that password whether on runtime via some config file or some KMS or anything. there is no straightforward answer to this. EOD we are adding a layer of protection.

Comment: Get the user to provide their own password, either through a system property, an environment variable, or some other method which suits your application.

Comment: no, becuasse the encryption password is in the source code declared:
    private static final char[] PASSWORD = "Unauthorized_Personel_Is_Unauthorized".toCharArray();

Comment: Obfuscation would just require you to re-arrange the data in some non-standard way. 
 If a program was trying to scan your code for the text _"password"_, you wouldn't want it to be able to decode the values around it.  I believe obfuscation is meant as a deterrent, and not necessarily a solution.  So, realistically, it could be a complete class with methods and fields.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you include the password in your executable code, it can be recovered by the user no matter how you obfuscate it, simply by using a debugger.

Comment: the question is not clearly enough? the encryption password at least in all documents i found it's allways on the source code or charger in a .properties file, obfuscate or encrypt it it will make it difficult, did you know how to accomplish that?

Comment: It's trivial to find the `setPassword` call and put a breakpoint there, so obfuscation buys you nothing. You haven't explained what information you want to protect from which attackers.